# print/display something in a Qt function call by a slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Here my problem, I am writing a C++ code using Qt signal and slots, I have somewhere a slot calling a function in which I would like to "check" the value of a data, for that I would like to print/display it somehow, but the methods I am used to used are not working at all.

Here my slot call:

```
        connect ( ButtonFreq[i], SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( CallVibration() ) );
```

First I tried to print in a box I have on my interface with all the log info, with exactly the same syntax I used to use:

```
QString name=this->getName();
QString PrevMess=ui.textBrowserCp2kCompRes->toPlainText();
if(PrevMess!="") PrevMess+="\n\n";
ui.textBrowserCp2kCompRes->setText(PrevMess+"get the name "+name);
```

it's not doing anything.
Then I tried to write in a file:

```
QFile file("/home/me/test");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
file.write(name);
```

the same, doing nothing.
So I understand I am doing something that is not allowed but I don't understand why neither how I could overcome it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Which version of Qt are you using?

Comment: I am using Qt5.9.3

Comment: If you use Qt5 why do you stick to this terrible old-fashioned `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros? The new Qt5 style to manage signals and slots by function pointers grants compile-time checking. Additionally, you can bind any matching function or member function without remarking them as slot, and you can use lambdas as adapters to make slots matching to signals.

Comment: I am using Qt5.9.1 cause my code is part of sth using this Qt, but I  doesn't know these new methods.

Comment: yes it might be due to the connection method which was used in qt4, try the slot with a simple ui.textBrowserCp2kCompRes->append("my test 1");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't use QDebug if you only want to check if it's working? You can put in `on_pushButton`:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    qDebug () << name;
}
```

The output will be printed to the console of your QT creator (also in GUI mode).

Comment: well no, in fact I am not directly executing the code I am writing, it's an app in a greater structure and I don't have access to the log...

Comment: So you definitely need to provide more details to your questions. Why you don't have access to native QT tools like its console?

Comment: Oh I found how to force to print the log. And weel same than other method outside of the function called by the slot it's printing fine, in it it's printing nothing.